# webrick server not running on ruby version 5.0.7.2 on CLOUD9 IDE on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, webrick, aws-cloud9

I got into the app directory inside the blog folder
and ran a command to start the WEBRick server:

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

[CODE CONSOLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7qFg.png)

Above is the link for the image of my console.
Please HELP

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the puma server that you currently have loading will work out fine anyway.